# 500 error with .jpg when using custom exception handling with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I've got a test service I've written that just takes a file title as a parameter, i.e. testfile.jpg.. all this is doing is throwing my custom exception with a custom exception message. When I use 'testfile' as the parameter, it works fine.. gives 400 error status code. If I use 'testfile.jpg' it doesn't seem to like the extension in there and the error status code comes back as 500 internal error instead.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this? so it displays the correct 400 error status code when using files with the extension in there (i.e. testfile.jpg) ?

The controller:

```
    @ApiOperation("Tests")
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/testingURL/{test}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getTestingURL(@PathVariable String test) throws Exception{
        return assetStoreService.test(test);
    }
```

Service method:

```
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> test(final String test) throws CustomTestException{
    if(!test.isEmpty()){
        exceptionThrower();
    }
    TestImage testImage = new TestImage();
        return getResponseEntity(testImage);
    }
```

exceptionThrower:

```
    private void exceptionThrower() throws CustomTestException {
        throw new CustomTestException("blahbah");
    }
```

CustomTestException.java:

```
public class CustomTestException extends Exception {
    public CustomTestException(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Exception handler:

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomTestException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity handleCustomTestException (HttpServletRequest request, CustomTestException ex){
        request.removeAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);
        TestError testError = new TestError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,ex.getMessage(),ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(testError, new HttpHeaders(), testError.getStatus());
    }
```

The bit below, is to remove the accepted return types (images) so it can return the exception json object response:

```
    request.removeAttribute(
            HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off part of content negotiations as a best practice. If you still want to use extension try this in application.properties file

spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-path-extension=true